# Can I parse some F# code at run-time that reference types in my current assembly?

Tags: f#, f#-compiler-services

Say I have the following type defined:

```
type Foo = { A: string; B: int }
```

I want a function `parse`, such that:

```
let myfoo = parse<Foo> "{A = \"foo\"; B = 5}"
```

gives me an instance of type Foo (or error).

Is this possible using FSharp.Compiler.Service?

**UPDATE:**

While there are other questions that address parsing of F# code, they don't address having references in the current assembly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to execute F# code found in a string in a compiled F# program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1156665/how-to-execute-f-code-found-in-a-string-in-a-compiled-f-program)

Comment: Of interest: https://fsharp.github.io/FSharp.Compiler.Service/interactive.html

Comment: In particular, this question is looking to address compilation of code with references back to this current assembly, and instantiation of values in the *current* process space, which differs from the question above. Also the above question is 10 years old, and its answers are no longer relevant.

Comment: Thanks @CaringDev. The interactive, I believe works in its own process space as well (and if it it doesn't), communicates via streams with the calling code.

I'm quite sure this is possible with the FSharp.Compiler.Service, however I'm looking for advice from those more experienced with the Compiler Service at which level I need to be integrating -- untyped AST level, OR after the type references are resolved, with an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by referencing the current assembly from the hosted F# interactive - this only works if you are running this from a compiled program (which has assembly located on disk) and if your types are public, but it may do the trick in your case.

Given the [usual setup documented on the Embedding F# Interactive page](https://fsharp.github.io/FSharp.Compiler.Service/interactive.html), you can do something like this:

```
module Program

type Test = { A:int; B:string }

// (omitted code to initialize the fsi service)
let fsiSession = FsiEvaluationSession.Create(...)    

// Run #r command to reference the current assembly  
let loc = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location
fsiSession.EvalInteraction(sprintf "#r @\"%s\"" loc)

// Open the module or namespace containing your types
fsiSession.EvalInteraction("open Program")

// Evaluate code using the type and cast it back to our type
let value = fsiSession.EvalExpression("{A=0; B=\"hi\"}").Value.ReflectionValue :?> Test
printfn "%A" value
```